# Which git worktree commands should I use to have two local directories "share the same remote"

Tags: git, mercurial, git-worktree

In Mercurial when I have a repository checked-out in my local directory "C:\my-projects\my-old-hg-repo-checkout", with the "**hg share**" extension enabled, command `hg share C:\my-projects\my-old-hg-repo-checkout C:\my-projects\my-new-hg-repo-checkout` will create a new local directory that "shares the same remote" (i.e if I pull remote changes in one directory, they are visible in the other).

How exactly can I do the same thing with my local check-out of a git directory, "C:\my-projects\my-old-git-repo-checkout", that I want to duplicate in "C:\my-projects\my-new-git-repo-checkout" (while ensuring they "share the same remote", i.e pulling remote changes from one directory will make them visible in the other)?

Comment: Is "shares the same remote" an accurate description of what `hg share` does? It shares the LOCAL internal "database" of HG data; whether or not it also syncs with the same distant clone by default on a push/pull seems like a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `git worktree` command to create additional worktrees for your local git repo:

```
git clone <url of remote repo>
cd <directory>
git worktree add <path-to-new-directory> <branch_name>
```

You now have two worktrees for your git repo, each in different directories.  You can add as many worktrees you want with additional `git worktree add` commands.  Note that two worktrees cannot have the same branch checked out.

`git fetch` updates the local repo from the remote, and as both worktrees are attached to the same local repo, you will have updated information in both worktrees.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree for documentation on the `git worktree` command.